# LVM_SORTITEMS: cancelling

Tags: c++, listview, win32gui

I am using a win32 listview using the win32 api

I have a custom sort function that calls some lengthy function in my app, and I want the user to be able to tell the listview to "stop sorting now". Sure I can return from my lengthy sort compare function early, but the listview then calls the sort function over and over!

I am invoking the sort using the following code:
`SendMessage(hWndLv, LVM_SORTITEMS, lParamSort, pfnMyCompare)`

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think cancelling is possible.  How about pre-computing the sort criteria ?

Comment: Sorting should not be a lengthy operation. There is no way to cancel it. Exiting the sort function is the only option.

Comment: Maybe if pfnMyCompare immediately returns 0, it would finish faster at least. After sort is completed, redrawing items may take a while depending on how your drawing is implemented.

Comment: Thanks, I have indeed found that just returning zero after the search has been cancelled (without comparing anything) does the job!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have indeed found that just returning zero after the search has been cancelled (without comparing anything) does the job!